# What is the difference between Google Ads 'Operations' and 'Requests'?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I have a question about googleads api.

[image]

In the picture you can see "Daily Operational Limit - 10.000 operations / day" and "Daily Report Request Limit - 1.000 requests / day"

any idea what´s the difference between operation and request?

the link: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/access-levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AdWords API documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/rate-limits):

> **Difference between a request and an operation**
>
> So what's the difference between RequestsPerMinute and OperationsPerMinute? Every SOAP service call is counted as a Request. For example, every time you call CampaignService.mutate(), it's counted as one request. However, within the mutate request, you may have passed 100 CampaignOperations--this would be counted as 100 operations!
>
> In the example above, while you may have avoided a RequestPerMinute rate limit by combining multiple operations into one request, you may still hit an OperationsPerMinute rate limit.
>
> You can find more examples on how operations are counted on the Rate Sheet page.

Basically a request is decomposed in a set of operations. For examples, see the documentation section : [Rate Sheet and Non-Compliance Fees](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/ratesheet)